# Issue with Terra: Buffer on a SpatRaster returns random results, but never the desired result

Tags: r, buffer, terra

I have a problem with my code in R. So, i have a SpatRaster (which im not allowed to provide), that i want to use as a mask. The resolution is 5 Meters, crs is EPSG:32632. Extent is roughly 10km². The Values of the desired shape are all 1 and all other raster values are NA. So i want to create a buffer of 15 Meters around the shape like in the example.

I'm using R 4.3.1 and RStudio, working in a Markdown.
Package *terra* verion 1.7-55

```
library(terra)

# Load example file
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r <- project(r, "EPSG:32632")
r <- ifel(r<400, NA, 1)

# Create buffer of 3 Pixels
b <- buffer(r, width = xres(r)*3)

# Show results
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(r)
plot(b)
```

[Plot without buffer and plot with buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7q5a.png)

The result ends up with a raster image where all values in the raster are 1. I tried changing some values, e.g. i changed width to 150, then the buffer works sometimes as desired and i get a 150m buffer (at least fits from visual judgement). But sometimes the 150 buffer also returns an all TRUE Raster image. No other width has yet created a visual appealing result at all. And since this seems to occur random i have no further idea what to do...

Update: While writing this issue, i ran the code (with width 15) again and again stupidly without changing anything, and now i got a fitting result. I safed it for now, but I'm still extremely confused and need my code for further reproduction. So I'm still interested in the error here..

Update 2: Ive added an example, however i cant reproduce the error without the actual dataset. In my case this code mostly produced a shape containing only the value 1, without any NAs or 0. But running the code again and again fixed it eventually.

Update 3:
The Bug still occurs with the exact same code. The result i get looks like that, however, the example doesnt generate this bug..

[Actual plot without buffer and with buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG2Go.png)

I really dont know whats wrong with it, since the same code works with the examples.

Thanks in regards!

Comment: I'm not sure what result you expected from `terra:buffer`. A short look into the help file shows "SpatRaster cells inside the buffer distance get a value of 1. ". Maybe you can rephrase your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* that illustrates the problem you have. That is, even if you *could* share your data, we would not want it. Instead, create example data that is similar to your real data with code, or use a file that ships with R.

Comment: You might want to look at `?terra::extend` with, it appears, y = c(3,3,3,3), with fill = NA to arrive at your buffered mask. I'm often wrong on these suggestions, but it could be worth a read.

Comment: @rosapluesch Exactly. In my case all NA-Values do get the value of 1, not just those inside the buffer distance. But randomly only the values inside the buffer distance get a value of 1, as its supposed to work. 
Sorry if some sentences sound strange, I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thanks for welcoming me! Okay, ill try to create one and edit my post. The problem doesnt occur on a small example file, like in the example from the buffer function, so i try if it occurs on a SpatRaster with the same specs as mine. Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the solution is the available RAM. If i run `gc()` right before `buffer()`, the result always is the desired result. I have 16GB RAM, im close to 10GB Ram used when `buffer()` is used in the script. I don't know the threshold, how much RAM has to be available for `buffer()` to work properly, but cleaning up here and there in the script seems to be a good idea.

Thanks for your help!